# Environment variable to get the build output path in VS TFS 2015 integrated Release

Tags: tfs, release, tfs-2015

I am using Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 with Update 1.
With this, Microsoft has provided a 'Release' option to deploy applications after successful build. This doesn't require a "Release Management" tool.

There are several pre-defined tasks available in this Integrated Release to copy files to deployment servers. But what I wanted is to create a custom powershell script to copy files from the build output folder(a network path) to my deployment servers(Dev, test, etc).
[Add Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot3lF.jpg)

This requires the help of Environment Variables to find the build output. 
I have previously gone through the below link for list of variables, https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#predefvariables

Please help me to identify the Environment variable that gives me the build output path(Not Agent path) specific to my release.
I already checked

```
[SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY] --> [C:\agentx\_work\0d0415c0f]

[AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\agentx\_work\0d0415c0f]
```

which gives us the path in agent server and not the build output path.
What I require is an env variable to get me `\\\Network\devops\Test\Builds\TestApp\20160122.10`

My build is configured to copy build output files to a network path.

Comment: Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) what you're looking for?

Comment: What "Release" option are you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the location of the drop's environment variable. Check TF_BUILD environment variable `TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION`.